# How to style react native picker

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using [Beefe's react-native-picker](https://github.com/beefe/react-native-picker) and I want to add custom styles.

I have an method that renders the picker as follows:

```
renderModal() {
        if (!this.state.itemPickerVisible) return;
        return (
            <View>
                {
                    Picker.init({
                        pickerData: map(categories, cat => cat.code + "." + cat.name),
                        pickerTitleText: gettext("Please select"),
                        pickerConfirmBtnText: gettext("Done"),
                        pickerCancelBtnText: gettext("Cancel"),
                        selectedValue: [this.state.selectedValue.code],
                        pickerBg: [255, 255, 255, 1],
                        onPickerConfirm: data => {
                            let code = data[0].substring(0, data[0].indexOf('.'));
                            this.setState({selectedValue: get_category(code), itemPickerVisible: false}, () => this.selectedItem());
                        },
                        onPickerCancel: data => {
                            Picker.hide();
                        },
                        onPickerSelect: data => {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    })
                }
                {
                    Picker.show()
                }
            </View>
        )
    }
```

And the `render` method is as follows:

```
render() {
        let value = this.props.value ? this.props.value.name : "";
        return (
            <View style={{
                borderLeftWidth: 4,
                borderLeftColor: this.props.mandatory ? this.props.value == null ? s.paletteMandatory : s.success : '#fff'
            }}>
                {this.renderModal()}
                <ItemDetail locked={this.props.locked} selectItem={this.selectItem.bind(this)}
                            resetItem={this.resetItem.bind(this)} title={this.props.title} value={value}
                            icon={this.props.icon}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

Is there any way to add custom style (fontFamily, color) to the picker items?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [component docs](https://github.com/beefe/react-native-picker#params) there are several parameters you can pass to init function.

```
Picker.init({
        pickerTitleColor: [90, 90, 90, 1], // RGBA values
        pickerData: data,
        selectedValue: [59],
        onPickerConfirm: data => {
            console.log(data);
        },
        onPickerCancel: data => {
            console.log(data);
        },
        onPickerSelect: data => {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    Picker.show();
```

Comment: I saw that, but I want to style `fontFamily` of the items, and in the docs I couldn't find it.

Comment: To change fontFamily you can force style to something else for the entire component. The component probobly using the default fontFamily. Wrap the Picker component with a View and set fontFamily of that View for something else. Font Families change from OS to OS so I'll suggest you to use the default fontFamilies unless you are adding a font file to your project.

Comment: I tried to add style to the view but it won't  work.

Comment: I checked the source code for the component and I don't think you can change the font. Maybe you can consider using another picker component. A quick google search might give you some more option or you can try to ask on github to the developer.